# System of linear congruence, not relatively prime

Tags: reference-request, modular-arithmetic

Consider we have the following set of congruences

$$x\equiv b_i \pmod {m_i}$$
for all $1\leq i\leq d$. $m_i$'s doesn't have to be relatively prime, so the Chinese remainder theorem doesn't work here. Assume that we already have the prime factorization of each $m_i$.

I seek some reference that document an algorithm and it's complexity to solve this problem. Here solve means find the smallest non-negative solution.

**Edit:** This is not a homework problem. I actually want some paper that has this result so I can cite for a paper. Since it looks like this should be well known, but I'm not familiar in these algorithms.

The motivation is to find if there exist a solution to $a^x=b$, where $a$ and $b$ are elements in a finite abelian group, and $x$ is a natural number.

As @fgrieu hinted in the comment.

If I apply the factorization, I can get an algorithm of the following form:

Write $m_i$ as product of primes, then now I have $x\equiv b_i \pmod {p_{i,j}^{e_i}}$. Assume the number of distinct primes involved is at most $k$, then now we have $O(dk)$ equations.

For each prime $p$, we will have 
$x\equiv b_i \pmod {p^{e_i}}$

Assume wlog $e_i\geq e_{i-1}$. 
Looking at $x\equiv b_i \pmod {p^{e_i}}$ and $x\equiv b_{i-1} \pmod {p^{e_{i-1}}}$, we can either detect a conflict, or $x\equiv b_i \pmod {p^{e_i}} \implies x\equiv b_{i-1} \pmod {p^{e_{i-1}}}$. Looks like this computation reduces to checking if $p^{e_{i-1}}$ divides $b_i-b_{i-1}$.

These operations will take $O(dk)$ divisibility checks. 
If all the above reduction can be done, we can reduce the problem to one CRT, so the final CRT takes $O(d)$ arithmetic operations.

Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^d m_i$. There are a total $O(dk)$ arithmetic operations, all numbers are $O(\log n)$ bits.
It seems one can do better by actually showing the sum of the exponents is at most $\log n$ and get the bound of $O(\log n)$ arithmetic operations instead.

Comment: Hint: use that you know the factorization of all the $m_i$ to write an equivalent system of equations where all the ${m_i}'$ are prime; check if it has solutions; and determine them using the CRT. $\;$ That can be made to work even if you do not known the factorizations of the $m_i$, by using $\gcd$. Complexity is is low, dominated by the final CRT step, I guess.

Comment: I need reference on the actual complexity of any known algorithm. I feel this is more likely to be known to crypto people.